# I have an issue with the navbar in mobile

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The problem with my navbar is that everything works fine in the desktop version and even when I use the developer tools to see how it should look like in smartphones, ipads, etc, it seems to adjust just fine. But when I open my webpage in any smartphone the icon on the navbar seems like a little dot and the height of the navbar change. Any ideas on how to fix this?

[This is how it looks like in the developers tool of Chrome. Everything just fine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1eooR.png)

[This is how it actually looks like in smartphone or tablet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TLroT.png)

Here's the html code of the navbar

```
<!-- Only on smartphones -->
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-controls="navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Navegation Menu">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>

<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#about" class="nav-link">About me</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#academic" class="nav-link">Academic</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#experience" class="nav-link">Experience</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#skills" class="nav-link">Skills</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#social" class="nav-link">Social</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
            <a href="#contact" class="nav-link">Contact me</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS code

```
navbar-brand img {
    margin: auto;
    border-radius: 5px;
    border: solid 2px rgb(108, 186, 135);
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
}
```

Comment: Your HTML markup should not really change whether it's for desktop or mobile views, it is the CSS code that changes.

Comment: It doesn't seem like there's enough information here to help. It's your logo that looks broken, and that markup isn't shown.

Comment: The markup of the logo is a simple one liner and the image original size is 200x200 px. The problem is that it works perfectly fine in the developer tool of Chrome, but somehow it gets distorted in the actual smartphone.

Answer (score 0):

Try this HTML markup

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
    <a href="#" class="navbar-brand">Brand</a>
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarCollapse">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarCollapse">
        <div class="navbar-nav">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link active">Home</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Profile</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Messages</a>
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link disabled" tabindex="-1">Reports</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
            <a href="#" class="nav-item nav-link">Login</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

With the Bootstrap CSS and JS libraries:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

More info about getting started with Boostrap: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/